# Adding 'Reader' role to Application in Azure Powershell fails in file upload

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm using the following code to add the 'Reader' role to my application in the Azure Cloud Shell. I use a Powershell script and upload it to a file storage, then call it on Cloud Shell. See below:

```
Install-Module Az -Scope CurrentUser
Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication
az login

function Add-ReaderRole {

    param(
        $appName
    )
    $spId = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($appName)'").ObjectId
    $subscriptionId = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.id
    New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spId -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -Scope "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId"

}
```

[image]

I'm having a problem where this part of the code will fail with a 'Bad Request' when I run the file. I tried to paste the code in manually to Cloud Shell and it ran fine and added the 'Reader' role. Does anyone know why this code inside the file fails but manually pasting it in runs fine?

Answer (score 0):

**To add 'Reader' role to Application in Azure PowerShell using file upload, check the below:**

Click on manage file share.

[image]

Then click on Add directory:

[image]

**Save the below script and upload it in the new directory created:**

```
Connect-AzAccount -UseDeviceAuthentication

$appName = "CLIApp"
$spId = (Get-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName $appName).Id
$subscriptionId = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.id
New-AzRoleAssignment -ObjectId $spId -RoleDefinitionName "Reader" -Scope "/subscriptions/$subscriptionId"
```

[image]

Now **connect to the file share and run the file**:

```
cd clouddrive
dir

cd ./Powershell/  #NewDirectoryName
dir

./RukkRoleAssignmentPs.ps1 #FileName
```

[image]

***The reader role assigned successfully to the Service Principal:***

[image]

**If still issue persists,** refer this below blog for more in detail:

[Upload and run an Azure PowerShell script from your clouddrive in Azure Cloud Shell by Wim Matthyssen](https://wmatthyssen.com/2022/02/01/upload-and-run-an-azure-powershell-script-from-your-clouddrive-in-azure-cloud-shell/)